# Раскрутка андроид-приложений

Tags: android, раскрутка

Собственно вопрос в следующем: какой способ раскрутки приложений принес вам наибольшую выгоду? Какие провайдеры рекламы лучше по-вашему, какие хуже? Рентабельна ли разработка под андроид и хватит ли разработчику на хлебушек?

Интересно ваше мнение.

Comment: Комментьарий к пред.вопросу (немогу там отписать), узнают они или с маркета или с крупных форумов типа xda (ну я на форумы хоть и постю но просмотров темы очень мало). То что игра растет в рейтинге пока ничего не дает, но все равно видна эффективность каких то моих действий над раскруткой, первое - никто не застрахован от сюрпризов маркета, а второе пока очень мало загрузок (300-500 день). Да по маркету тоже находят. Пишу на самодельном движке, читал какую-то книгу, там автор рассказывал и писал его по ходу, я потом относительно сильно до своих нужд доработал. Но нужно браться за OpenGL 2D.

Comment: Так есть же AndEngine, libgdx - отличные штуку...или Cocos2DX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучшая раскрутка, по моему мнению, это - наличие множества хороших ревью на вашу игру/приложение на различных сайтах.

По рекламе работал с AdMob - скажу одно, дорого, минимум получается 250 кликов за 10 уе.

Разработка рентабельна, при хороших проектах прибыль достаточно высокая, но кайф могут обломать "баги маркета" после которых ваше приложение может упасть в числе загрузок в день/потерять позиции в рейтингах.

Comment: Знаю, у нас уже несколько приложений в маркете:) И это только половина проблем. Вторая - фрагментация. То бишь на рекламе заработать вам не удалось?

Comment: Удавалось до начала "сюрпризов")

Comment: Высокая прибыль? Вы работаете на себя?

Comment: Достаточно для 100к установок. Да

Comment: Это объясняет многое:) Но все же, не каждое приложение может выстрелить. Вы пиарились на многих сайтах, чтобы получить 100к, либо хитрости были, вроде платы за скачку?

Comment: Вообще ничего не делал) Честно. Сейчас игру запустили, уже 4 ревью есть на различных сайтах (хороших, даже на xda отписали про нас), но меня не радует, что активные инсталлы опять не обновляется. Кстати, главное бесит, что профф. сайты ревьюшные мне даже не отвечают, а различные сайты типа AndGeeks, XDA, еше несколько французских и итальнских сайтов. (Это я уже все про новую игру, которую на днях выложили.)

Comment: Ну вот, к теме о силе ревью, игру релизнули в тот четверг, сейчас она 207! Место в Top Free in Brain & Puzzle (English) и 56 тамже только на русском языке.

Comment: Поздравляю! Можете пиариться ничего неделая:) Интересно, как это они сами пишут? Тупо по маркету лазеют и находят интересное для себя?
Кстати, на каком движке пишете игры?

Answer (score 0):

Есть сайт [BoostApp](http://boost-app.com), на котором есть клевые статьи про [продвижение на Google Play](http://boost-app.com/ru/stati/80-google-play/73-prodvizhenie-na-google-play) и [маркетинг андроид приложений](http://boost-app.com/ru/stati/80-google-play/74-pay-per-install-raskrutka-prilozhenij-s-fiksirovannoj-platoj-za-ustanovku) вообще. Реально все разложено по полочкам, во второй статье анализируются разные способы раскрутки (реклама, сети pay per install). Также сам BoostApp специализируется на раскрутке Андроид приложений. Я пользовался их услугами, работает намного лучше чем тот же Admob с точки зрения затрат. Вывел в топ категории в Google Play два своих приложения.
Статьи с обзорами - сложная тема. Это либо дорого, либо очень долго (договариваться, писать самому пресс-релизы и т.п.). 
Разработка может быть вполне рентабельна - нужно только грамотно продумать монетизацию.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае основным способом раскрутки является размещение обзоров в блогах. Реклмаой особо не занимался. А вот обзоры очень хороший импульс придают - 7 - 10 000 установок, а потом по нарастающей само собой. У меня фремиум проги. Пользовался услугами [Иван PR](http://www.ivanpr.com/ru/), в Рунете и один раз в американских блогах засветился. Там на сайте, кстати, есть статьи о [раскрутке Android приложений](http://bit.ly/X82Puf). Рекомендую.